# How do I tell which view some gesture recognizer is attached to?

Tags: ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

How do I know what this thing is attached to? Does it engage when I click the image? the button? the content view?

[image]

Comment: If you add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to an Image view or label, then dont forget to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to an Image view or label, then
>   don't forget to set `isUserInteractionEnabled` property to `true`

Check `Referencing Outlet Connections` in `Connections Inspector` tab (Command + Option + 6)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply, by navigating to the IB, selecting your gesture recognizer and selecting connection inspector from the the utilities  (as you already did in the attached screenshot):

[image]

Which means that the gesture is connected to the main view of the controller.

---

In case if you are aiming to add the gesture recognizer to a specific component, would need to drag it into the desired component, as follows -let's assume that you want to add it for a label-:

[image]

Thus would notice when selecting the gesture recognizer that it is connected to the label:

[image]

---

**Setting the action:**

At this point, the gesture recognizer won't be trigged because it has no action:

[image]

If you are familiar with how to add an action for a button from the interface builder (select the button and <kbd>control</kbd> drag into the controller) you'd have to do the exact same thing for it:

[image]

Make sure to "Connection" to be "Action" instead of "Outlet".

Comment: Hey thanks, but my Tap Gesture recognizer doesn't seem to trigger the callback, do you have any ideas why? https://i.imgur.com/svDjVJ0.png

Comment: @AlanSTACK because it's action is *not* connected :)

Comment: How would I fix this then?